# Head meta rendered in body

Tags: next.js

I'm using next 5, in my project I have a `_document` file like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import Document, { Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'
import { extractCritical } from 'emotion-server'

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  static getInitialProps({ renderPage }) {
    const page = renderPage()
    const styles = extractCritical(page.html)
    return { ...page, ...styles }
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    const { __NEXT_DATA__, ids } = props
    if (ids) {
      debugger
      __NEXT_DATA__.emotion_ids = ids
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <html>
        <Head>
          <title>My Site</title>
          <meta charSet="utf-8" />
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
          <meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="fr_FR" />
          <meta property="og:site_name" content="My Site" />
          <meta name="twitter:site" content="@my_site" />
          <meta name="twitter:creator" content="@my_site" />
          <style dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.props.css }} />
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <div id="modal" style={{ display: 'none' }} />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </html>
    )
  }
}
```

And also a page usign the `<Head>` component from Next.

Wen I inspect the rendered page I can see those tags (from both `__document` and `<Head>`) in my `<body>`, but not in my `<head>` tag. Any clue on what may be happening ?

Comment: Did you find the solution to this?

Comment: Nope sorry :/
Answers below didn't help?

Answer (score 0):

For route pages (not `_document` itself), try to `import Head from "next/head";`.

That's what I do in Next.js 7 & 8, I suspect that the imports were the same back in version 5.

Answer (score 0):

You have to import the `Html` component from `next/document`